# How to use UIEdgeInsets property in Button in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiedgeinsets

I am new to iOS application development and wanted to know how to use `UIEdgeInsets` property in button so please guide me.

Answer (score 79):

UIButton has three properties of type UIEdgeInsets – `contentEdgeInsets`, `titleEdgeInsets`, and `imageEdgeInsets`. You can use these properties to assign specific insets for all button content, including both the title and the image, or one or the other individually.

You create UIEdgeInsets values using the `UIEdgeInsetsMake()` function. UIEdgeInsets encapsulates four different CGFloat values for the inset values of the top, left, bottom, and right (respectively) individually. Positive inset values shrink the content area, while negative inset values will effectively increase it.

If you have a more specific question about how to use UIEdgeInsets with UIButton, I suggest you rethink how to ask it and try again. :)

**Edit** (to address question in comment):
Sounds like you would want to do the following, then:

```
UIEdgeInsets titleInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0);
button.titleEdgeInsets = titleInsets;
```

Comment: i have a button and i want that the title of that button should be 7 to 9 character left even if i have set Alignment to Left property.

Comment: it's top, left, bottom, right: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: You can try it using this very simple app I've made https://github.com/tomas789/UIButtonEdgeInsets

Answer (score 3):

If you want an **extension** for Button and use simply, use this

> button.setInset(top: 0.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)

```
extension UIButton {
    /**
        Creates an edge inset for a button
        :param: top CGFLoat
        :param: left CGFLoat
        :param: bottom CGFLoat
        :param: right CGFLoat
    */
    func setInset(#top: CGFloat, left: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) {
           self.titleEdgeInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that sometimes, you will not need to set the contentEdgeInsets. Just give the button a larger height and width constraints. The title itself will be center automatically.